# Decrypting Data using Triple DES adds "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0" at the end of the original text

Tags: c#, php, encryption

I'm using the Triple DES algorithm for encrypting data using PHP. Then, I'm decrypting it using a C# Windows Forms application.

With some data, when I decrypt it, I find `\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0` at the end of the original text that was encrypted in PHP. What could be causing that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Encryption algorithms require the data to be a multiple of a certain number of bytes. If the data isn't the right length, null characters are added to pad the data. This is what you're seeing after decryption. This is expected, and you just need to strip them.

Comment: The problem is there's no way to know if the zero byte is from padding or because the plaintext byte is, in fact, zero.

Answer (score 2):

`mcrypt_encrypt` uses a poor choice of zero padding by default. Instead use PKCS7 padding, as is explained in the user comments on the [mcrypt_encrypt](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php) page.

Comment: This is the correct answer! For AES Encyption replacing PKCS7 padding retrieves the actual string without appending \0\0\0